# Query issue using INTERVAL

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using *iReport 5.1*, *JasperReports Server 5.1* and I'm having trouble with a query using `INTERVAL`. The query line I'm having trouble with is:

`AND I.created::DATE >= I.created::DATE - INTERVAL '$P{attribution_window_passed} days'`

I am passing the attribution window value from the main report to the subreport as a parameter. I validated the parameter value passed is working correctly by using a text field in the subreport. If I exclude and replace `$P{attribution_window_passed}` with an integer, the query runs fine, example:

`AND I.created::DATE >= I.created::DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'`

I believe the problem is escaping the single quote, I have tried with no luck:

- `'$P{attribution_window_passed} days'`
- `\' $P{attribution_window_passed} days'`
- `$P{attribution_window_passed} days`
- `$P{attribution_window_passed} ' days'`
- `\'$P{attribution_window_passed} days\'`
- `\\' $P{attribution_window_passed} days'`

I also tried changing `$P{attribution_window_passed}` to a string class instead of an integer class.

Any suggestions for using `INTERVAL` in a query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PostgreSQL. I changed Parameter 'attribution_window_passed' from Integer to String in both main and sub-reports. Then changed query select statement in main report to

- PC.attribution_window || ' days' as attribution_window

for concatenation and passed as parameter to subreport. The query in subreport now looks like

- AND PC.conversion_date - I.created <= $P{attribution_window_passed}::INTERVAL